# Prerelease tests with Bloom on first-release

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm releasing a package with bloom for the first time and I'd like to run a prerelease test.

I'm following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease
and everything works fine until I arrive at Step 4 here:
http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest#bloom.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-PrereleaseTest.2BAC8-indigo.Prepare_the_release

Now, obviously the pre-release site doesn't know my repository, yet, because there is not entry in the release.yaml file at all. However, if I do open the pull-request to get that in there, I'd release it without ever testing.
Am I missing some step in between or what is the correct way to proceed?

As a side-note I've entered bloom-release multiple times and it's bumped the version each time. Is there any way to reset that, so I don't have unnecessary versions in between? I'm OK with resetting the release repo as that's new anyways.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201954/prerelease-tests-with-bloom-on-first-release/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2015-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The prerelease website can test your package based on data from three places:

- The repository and branch listed in your `source` entry in the `distribution.yaml` on ros/rosdistro
- This is the `devel` option.
- The release repository and the "release" branch for each package.
- Since this is a branch it will be updated after you push from bloom, but before you submit the pull request.
- This is the `latest` option.
- The latest released version of your package.
- This is the `x.y.z` option, where `x`, `y`, and `z` are numbers for you package's most recent released version.

Now the question is, should you do a prerelease? The prerelease job does something that no other job does, it downloads, builds, and tests *released* packages which depend on your packages. This is really awesome if you are releasing a new version of a package which has already been released, but it is strictly less useful when you are releasing a package for the first time, since that means there are no released packages which can depend on you yet.

On the first release into a ROS distribution, I would recommend either just not doing a prerelease or doing the binary build test locally, see: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest#bloom.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-PrereleaseTest.2BAC8-indigo.Perform_the_pre-release_locally

For Jade we plan to roll out a new tool which allows you to do pre-releases locally and with more control. This should make it easier to debug pre-releases and faster to run them since you don't have to wait on our farm which gets pretty backed up on pre-releases.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3